# Calculate number of nights between 2 DateTimes

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a start DateTime and an end DateTime and need to calculate the number of nights (not days) between the two with a default/minimum value being 1.

I've got

```
int NumberOfDays = Convert.ToInt32((EndDateTime - StartDateTime).Days)
```

Which returns the number of days so is always over by 1. I'm not sure that subtracting 1 from the result is an appropriate solution.

I have also tried

```
int NumberOfDays = Convert.ToInt32((EndDateTime - StartDateTime).ToDays)
```

Which also returns the same result.

Is there a smarter solution other than subtracting 1 every time and making sure it never returns a 0?

Comment: Please add an example with two dates

Comment: also when does a *night* count as complete? (what if the start is at 4am for example? What about 7am?)

Comment: are you including time in start date and end date ?

Comment: Is `1/1 23:59` to `1/3 0:01` considered one or two nights?

Comment: Currently you're calculating the number of 24 hour periods between your `DateTime`s which may or may not equate to "nights" depending on the time associated with each `DateTime` and on your definition of a "night".

Comment: Please disregard all of the above, my code is actually working I was just having a Monday-morning-pre-coffee moment. I've flagged this for admin to remove/mark as duplicate. Thanks for all the responses chaps!

Comment: way ahead of you, see above

Answer (score 1):

You can use extension method to make it simply reuse everywhere.

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static int NumberOfNights(this DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
    {
        //feel free to make here better
        var frm = date1 < date2 ? date1 : date2;
        var to = date1 < date2 ? date2 : date1;
        var totalDays = (int)(to-frm).TotalDays;
        return totalDays > 1 ? totalDays : 1;
    }
}
```

And use it like

```
var to = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
var frm = DateTime.Now;
frm.NumberOfNights(to)
```

Comment: Isn't it nicer to avoid naming your variable `from`?

Comment: When `to == from` the result should be 0, not 1. I thing the final line should be `return totalDays > 0 ? totalDays : 0;`

Comment: @user1793963 she wants it "default/minimum value being 1"

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry, I didn't read it correctly.